# How to get gazebo topic using c++ and ros?

Tags: ros, gazebo, topic, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using ROS, gazebo and c++ together to perform some tasks. In gazebo I launched "turtlebot_world.launch. It published " /gazebo/default/pose/info " which gives the information of robots position in gazebo. How can I take this topic in c++, does anyone knows ?

Also I have the function below but doesn't take any information or topic:

```
void subscribe_gazebo_pose()
{
    ros::NodeHandle ndh;
    ros::ServiceClient gms_c = ndh.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::GetModelState>("gazebo/default/pose/info");
    //gms_c.waitForExistence();
    gazebo_msgs::GetModelState getmodelstate;
    gms_c.call(getmodelstate);
    
    geometry_msgs::Pose pose;
    pose.position.x = getmodelstate.response.pose.position.x;
    pose.position.y = getmodelstate.response.pose.position.y;
    cout << pose.position.x << endl;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228606/how-to-get-gazebo-topic-using-c++-and-ros-?/) by [zuygar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21579/zuygar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you might be confusing message topics with services. is /gazebo/default/pose/info a topic, can you see if when you run "rostopic list" from a command line?

The code you have posted above attaches to a service provider not a message topic.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2016-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zuygar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21579/zuygar/) on 2016-03-10**:
I can't see any topic like above running "rostopic list". But if I run "gztopic list" I can see some topics like this:

/gazebo/default/pose/local/info

/gazebo/default/pose/info

/gazebo/default/gui

/gazebo/default/response

/gazebo/default/world_stats

/gazebo/default/selection